# Compare current location to database coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse.com database with two columns (containing over 5,000 rows of locations) that have latitudes and longitudes and I want to compare that to the user's current location. I have two problems: 1.) the formats between what CLLocation spits out is different than what the coordinates in the database are. 2.) I'm not sure how to actually compare the locations. My code that I have so far is below:

Example:

```
CLLocation coordinate formatting: +37.3175,-122.0419
Database coordinates formatting: 186760.6700N,635925.7100W  

// Code to pull from the database
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "faadatabase_jul15")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {
                    // var faaLoc is to combine the latitude and longitude
                    var faaLat:AnyObject? = object["ARPLatitudeS"]
                    var faaLon:AnyObject? = object["ARPLongitudeS"]
                    var faaLoc = "\(faaLat!),\(faaLon!)"

// I'm not sure how to compare the current location to the database location


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I apologize if the formatting is screwed up -- this is my first post here. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: i can't give you the answer but i can provide a general direction that you can explore. Firstly, you need to find out the Projection that these coordinates are based on. iOS Location API, Google Maps, Bing Maps and Apple's MapKit are using the WGS84 Projection (EPSG:4326). I recommend you convert your coordinates to this projection if it is not already. You can then use the method distanceFromLocation in CLLocation class to calculation the length between the 2 coordinates to work out if they are at the same spot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe they are all using WGS84 projection, the difference is the formatting of the coordinates. The coordinates in the database are in degrees decimal formatting while what Apple's MapKit displays is a little difference. I guess I need to reconcile those to start with -- then find a way to compare the current location to the database to see which is closest. That's the part I'm having the most trouble on.